# Getting 404 error while trying to load the default page in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, default

I am trying to set up the default page of my application to index.html

My folder structure is [image: folder structure]

My dispatcher-Servlet.xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.programcreek.helloworld.controller" /> -->
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>NewAppPoc</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <!-- <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> -->
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

I am trying to access http://localhost:7001/NewAppPoc/ so i get 404 error. I tried searching a lot but not able to get my index.html displayed I am sure I am doing something wrong but unable to find what. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the issue because there is no mapping that can proocess the `/WEB-INF/views/index.html` request.

The fastest solution is to turn your *.html* to *.jsp* files and the suffix of your *InternalResourceViewResolver* also from *.html* to *.jsp*. If you need to keep your html files you should configure them as static resource using [mvc:resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) tag in your configuration. Something like

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/index.html" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />
```

**a longer explanation**

The dynamic resources are hanled by servlets which are mapped to URLs. Now what happens with the initial request

1. Your initial request will be handled by the *DispatcherServlet* cause it is mapped with `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`
2. The handlder method returns the view name index
3. The view name is concatenated with the prefix and sufix becoming `/WEB-INF/views/index.html` and then forwarded to be handled by some other servlet
4. This will again be captured by the *DispatcherServlet*
5. No handler method will be found for the mapping `/WEB-INF/views/index.html` and at that point it fails.

If the view suffix was set to `.jsp` things would work out differently.
Servlet containters have a servlet that is mapped to `*.jsp` registered by defualt. For example tomcat's *web.xml* you'll see a *org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet* mapped to `*.jsp` or `*.jspx`, so in this case a view would be rendered

Comment: so I should remove <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/> from the dispatcher servlet and add a controller that maps '/' will that work?

Comment: not really, mapping via view-controller or through controller boils down to the same thing. To make it work, either change your index.html to index.jsp along with the suffix change. Or add an element to your config <mvc:resources mapping="/index.html" location="/WEB-INF/views/" /> which makes the request for a static resource, thus ommiting mapping issues

Comment: Actually now when I access index.html it displays the pagge but it doesnt load the css and js files these are also static resources rite so how to I map them in my html?

Comment: yes, you should configure a static mapping for that also, check the link in the answer. Based on your folder structure you should list  `<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />` `<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />` etc. Typically, people move all the static resources under a single folder in a webapp root, e.g. resources, and than map the  `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` choose what feels better for you

Comment: Just on more doubt we used /index.html and mapped the resource is there anyway to load it by default on '/'

Comment: for that you would have to follow the second approach, so to change to  index.jsp. The reason is that the most specific mapping will be handled first, and the root request "/" will always be captured by DispatcherServlet, while index.html as it is more specific will be handled as static

Answer (score 0):

All your requests are mapped to dispatcher servlet, that is why it tries to resolve a view for index.jsp using view resolver. Ideally you should put your static resources in a different folder like shown below.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/static/" />
```

Or add a controller for the home path "/" which returns 'index' then it will be resolved by view resolver correctly.

Comment: so I should remove <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/> from the dispatcher servlet and add a controller that maps '/' will that work?

Comment: This should also work, sorry i didnt see it first time. try removing welcome files from web.xml